# Integral of $\int x^2\sqrt{25-x^2}\,dx$ using cos-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have tried this integral with $\cos$ substitution, but I don't understand why it's wrong. So could you please tell me which step is wrong? Here are my steps:
$$
x=5\cos\theta\\
dx=-5\sinθ\,dθ\\
$$
therefore
\begin{align}
&(1)=\int\sqrt{25-25\cos^2θ}\left(25\cos^2θ\right)(-5\sinθ)\,dθ\\
&(2)=-5^4\int\sin^2θ\cos^2θ\,dθ\\
&\qquad\left(\sin2θ=2\sinθ\cosθ\implies\sin^22θ=4\sin^2θ\cos^2θ\right)\\
&(3)=\frac{-5^4}4\int\sin^22θ\,dθ\\
&\qquad\left(\sin^2θ=\frac12(1-\cos2θ)\implies\sin^22θ=\frac12(1-\cos4θ)\right)\\
&(4)=\frac{-5^4}8\int(1-\cos4θ)\,dθ\\
&(5)=\frac{-5^4}8\left(θ-\frac14\sin4θ\right)+C\\
&\qquad\left(\sin4θ=2\sin2θ\cos2θ=4\sinθ\cosθ\left(\cos^2θ-\sin^2θ\right)\right)\\
&(6)=\frac{-5^4}8\left(θ-\sinθ\cosθ\left(\cos^2θ-\sin^2θ\right)\right)+C\\
&\qquad\left(\cosθ=\frac x5\implies\sinθ=\frac{\sqrt{25-x^2}}5\right)\\
&(7)=\frac{-5^4}8\left(\arccos\left(\frac x5\right)-\frac{\sqrt{25-x^2}}5*\frac x5*\frac{25-2x^2}{5^2}\right)+C\\
&(8)=\frac{-5^4}8\left(\arccos\left(\frac x5\right)-\frac{x\sqrt{25-x^2}}{25}*\frac{25-2x^2}{25}\right)+C\\
\end{align}

Comment: You've been told to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) before, and you've been here long enough to know that mathematics in questions is expected to be formatted that way. You know that the question was all but impossible to read the way you originally posted it.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I have tried it and it was a mess, so I just gave up. Will try to do it right now by looking at edits.

Comment: It can be a steep learning curve at first, but it just takes practice. I appreciate that you're making the effort to learn, however; that's more than can be said for some other new users.

Comment: In the first line you have replaced $x^2$ by $(5\cos \theta)$ rather than by $(5\cos \theta)^2$.  So the rest is probably wrong as well.

Comment: Oh, that's a typo but I used (5cos theta)^2 correctly in my calculation

Answer (score 2):

$-5^4\int \sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta \ d\theta \\
-\frac {5^4}{4}\int \sin^2 2\theta \ d\theta\\
-\frac {5^4}{8}\int 1  - \cos 4\theta \ d\theta\\
-\frac {5^4}{8}(\theta  - \frac 14 \sin 4\theta)  + C\\
-\frac {5^4}{8}(\arccos \frac {\theta}{5}  - \frac 14 (2\sin 2\theta\cos 2\theta))  + C\\
-\frac {5^4}{8}(\arccos \frac {\theta}{5}  - \sin \theta\cos\theta(2\cos^2\theta -
 1))  + C\\
-\frac {5^4}{8}(\arccos \frac {\theta}{5}  - \sqrt {1-\frac {x^2}{25}}(\frac {x}{5})(2\frac {x^2}{25} - 1))  + C\\
\frac {1}{8} (-5^4\arccos \frac {x}{5}  +  (\sqrt {25- x^2})(x)(2x^2 - 25))  + C\\
$

Comment: cos2θ=cos^2θ-sin^2θ right? How do you get 2cos^2θ-1? And aren't you supposed to replace arccos theta/5 with arccos x/5 ?

Comment: Also when I enter that antiderivative, it doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: $\cos^2\theta - \sin^2 \theta = 2\cos^2 \theta - 1 = 1-2\sin^2\theta$

Comment: But how come if I enter F(2) in the formula, I get -110 (approximately)? When I use sin-substitution, I get a normal answer which is correct, but I always get a weird one using cos-substitution. The correct answer of F (2) should be 12,6 which is the same answer I get with the sin-sub.

Comment: $\frac {1}{8} (-625\arccos \frac {x}{5}  +  (\sqrt {25- x^2})(x)(2x^2 - 25))  + C = \frac {1}{8} (625\arcsin \frac {x}{5}  +  (\sqrt {25- x^2})(x)(2x^2 - 25))  + C$

Comment: At $x = 2$ the RHS evaluates to $-110.05 + C $ and the LHS evaluates to $12.67+C.$  The difference in the constant of integration of the two is  $\frac {625\pi}{8}$

Comment: I don't really understand that part. Why is there a difference in the constant of integration? Shouldn't you get the same number? The antiderivative should give you the immediate area right?

Comment: That is what the $+C$ is all about.  Depending on the steps you take in the integration, you may get answers that differ by a constant.  i.e. $\int 2\sin x \cos x = \sin^2 x +C= -\cos^2 x +D = -\frac 12 \cos 2x + E$

Comment: And how do you know the value of C? Because if I were to use that antiderivative with the cos-sub, I will get a value which differs from the value with the sin-sub. So you get different answers for the area right? And do you also know what is wrong with my steps?

Comment: If you have a definite integral, then it cancels out when you subtract the evaluation at the lower bound from the evaluation at the upper bound.  When you have an indefinite integral, you don't evaluate the constant.  It is arbitrary, it could be anything.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! That was really helpful. Do you know what is wrong with my steps though?